# Stack Navigator flow issue with TabRouter

Tags: react-native

Stack Navigator "Root"
--Stack Navigation A
   -- SN Login
   -- SN Signup
   -- SN HOME
Initial Route is "LOGIN"

HOME contain tab navigation
--Tab Navigator

--- TAB Navigator A

----Screen "Setting"

--- TAB Navigator B

----Screen "1"

----Screen "Setting"

**App.js**

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp
  },
  TermsConditions: {
    screen: TermsConditions
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home 
  },
    Setting: {
        screen: Setting
    }
}, {

  initialRouteName: "Login",
  headerMode: "none",
  // mode: 'modal',
  navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false
  }
});
```

When user login, navigate to "Home" screen -- End open the Truck as initial route.
**Home.js**

```
const HomeNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Trucks
    },
    TruckDetailController: {
      screen: TruckDetailController
    },
    Setting: {
      screen: Setting
    },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

const FavouriteNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Favourite: {
      screen: Favourite
    },
    TruckDetailController: {
      screen: TruckDetailController
    },
    Setting: {
      screen: Setting
    },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Favourite",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
const TabRoute = TabRouter(
  {
    Trucks: {
      screen: HomeNavigation
    },
    Favourite: {
      screen: FavouriteNavigation
    },
    Loyalty: {
      screen: Loyalty
    },
    Offer: {
      screen: Offer
    }
  },
  { initialRouteName: "Trucks" }
);
```

I Just want to logout from setting and switch to "Stack Navigation A -- Login" screen.

If anybody will give the solution for above so its appreciable and make a good point. :)

Comment: I have already tried all the scenario of react navigation :(

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. The first, is to use the `Back` action with a key (you'll have to save the key for the Feed screen when you're there).

The second is to use `Reset` as you have, but you misunderstood the role of the actions array - it is only intended for building a stack for a stack navigator.

To perform the inner stack-navigator navigation, you'll have to specify an action inside the navigation action:

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: '1',
      params: {},
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Feed'
      })
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its give me error "Invariant Violation : there should always be only one scene active, not 0". Please help me to solved this issue.:)

Comment: I have update my question, please check and provide me solution if anyone has.

Comment: Can you post the actual code for your navigator/screen setup?

Comment: I have again give navigation flow by which you can understand the flow.

Comment: Your navigation looks a bit messy. First, avoid setting the same name (key) in different navigators - when you navigate, the state machine won't know which one to go to. Also, I can't see where you use `AppNavigator` at all.

Comment: Thanks, Form Tab A & Tab B, we need to open same Setting screen thatsway I have to take "Setting" screen on both Tab. Can you please provide me ans how to switch from Tab navigation to Login screen. I am stuck from 2 days. I have tried all the available solution like which you provided me. Please help...